# amd64_edac_mod.ko(Error Detection and Correction driver) not loading with the latest kernel to check RAS

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04, kernel-module, ecc, amd-ryzen

I am trying to enable ECC to confirm RAS feature in **ubuntu-18.04**

Its GIGABYTE BIOS mode, I have checked ECC option, but it is not present.
and details of server is:

```
:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              64
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-63
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  32
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        4
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               8
Model name:          AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2990WX 32-Core Processor
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             1715.339
...
```

**AMD64 EDAC driver for ECC checking**
Cloned latest kernel "5.3.0-rc1" and enabled EDAC related configs, compiled and generated debians.

I installed kernel image and headers debians in ubutnu18.04.

after boot i am not able to list the edac module **amd64_edac_mod.ko** in "lsmod"

```
:~$ lsmod | grep edac
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
```

Check the dmesg logs, I am seeing below error messages:

```
[   17.489578] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[   17.489580] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[   17.489584] EDAC amd64: Node 1: DRAM ECC disabled.
[   17.489585] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
```

But There is no logs related to **AMD64_EDAC Driver initialization**

Again check the path whether drivers compiled or not as below and **amd64_edac_mod.ko** present.

```
:~$ ls /lib/modules/5.3.0-rc1-test/kernel/drivers/edac/
**amd64_edac_mod.ko**  **edac_mce_amd.ko**  i3200_edac.ko  i5100_edac.ko  i7300_edac.ko   i82975x_edac.ko  pnd2_edac.ko  skx_edac.ko
e752x_edac.ko      i3000_edac.ko    i5000_edac.ko  i5400_edac.ko  i7core_edac.ko  ie31200_edac.ko  sb_edac.ko    x38_edac.ko
```

Tried manually inserting the module, But its failing:

```
/lib/modules/5.3.0-rc1-test/kernel/drivers/edac$ sudo modprobe -v amd64_edac_mod
insmod /lib/modules/5.3.0-rc1-test/kernel/drivers/edac/amd64_edac_mod.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'amd64_edac_mod': No such device
```

Because of above driver not installed, under **mc** -> **mc0** and **mc1** memory controllers are not listed

```
:~$ ls /sys/devices/system/edac/mc/
power  subsystem  uevent
```

Could please help me the reason why the driver not installed ?

Comment: Added Code fix and Its working for latest AMD processors. So i am closing this Bug